# Problem with mail function with Zen Cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

When someone register in my site, he and me received email, that he register in the site and i that someone register in my site. But when someone order something, me and owner don;t get email for the order. In the options evrething is ok.

What to look for in php files and other files, to fix the automatic reply for mail and copy to my mail?

Answer (score 1):

If you've set your store to use "PHP" as your Email Transport Method, then your email is probably getting trapped by spam detections on your mailserver.  That is because your webserver will send the emails unauthenticated, which is the same way that spammers send emails.  If you instead switch to SMTPAUTH and provide your SMTP credentials, then Zen Cart will use those details to send the emails with authentication, and thereby not trigger that particular spam detection system.

See your admin screen at: Admin->Configuration->Email Options

Answer (score 0):

The mail is actually sent inside the order class ( */includes/classes/order.php* ), around line 1020 if you are using the latest version 1.3.9h. You can try echoing the arguments used in the mail call ( `zen_mail()` ) to check if everything is right.

Having said that, I would check the admin email settings twice and check that you can send/receive emails sent from the admin ( *Tools > Send email* ).

Also, do you perhaps have a contribution installed that could modify the order process? Have you check the error logs? If you are using 1.3.9 you have error logs saved by default on the cache folder. Otherwise, you can download and install a [very simple official contribution](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84613) to log the errors.